# If $F \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$ and $Y|F \sim \mathcal{N}(F, \tau^{-1} I )$, how to show $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma + \tau^{-1}I)$?

Tags: probability

Suppose that: $$F \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma)$$
$$Y|F \sim \mathcal{N}(F, \tau^{-1} I )$$

It then follows that:
$$
Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma + \tau^{-1}I)
$$

I am trying to then show that $Y-F$ and $F$ are independent. Is there an easy way to see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are satisfied that $Y-F$ and $F$ are jointly normal then all you need to do is show that $\operatorname{Cov}(Y-F, F) = \mathbf{0}$, but using linearity and the tower property of conditional expectations
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[(Y-F)F^T\right] &= \mathbb{E}[YF^T] - \mathbb{E}[FF^T]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbb{E}\left[YF^T\mid F \right]\right] - \mathbb{E}\left[ FF^T\right] \\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbb{E}\left[Y\mid F \right]F^T\right] - \mathbb{E}\left[ FF^T\right] \\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[ FF^T\right] - \mathbb{E}\left[ FF^T\right].
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Regarding the two being jointly normal, is that an assumption that needs to be made?

Comment: In general yes - otherwise it would not be enough to simply check the covariance and instead you would have to check more fundamental distributional properties, for example demonstrating that the density (or dist.) factors as $p(Y-F, F) = p(Y-F)p(F)$. There being jointly normal is immediate because $(Y-F, F)$ is a linear transformation of $(Y, F)$ which is jointly normal.

Comment: Just one more thing, does $(Y,F)$ being jointly normal follow from the conditional relation above? Where does it come from?

Comment: Yes it follows from the conditional relationship above, write the density as $p(Y, F) = p(Y|F)p(F)$ and identifying it with the pdf of a joint Gaussian